# Adding a list to a list of lists

Tags: python, list

`list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`
`list_to_add=["A","B","C"]`

I would like the result to be that list_of_lists will become:
`[["A","B","C"],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

Thanks!

Comment: use `list.insert(index,elements)` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append` to add an element to the end of the list, but if you want to add it to the front (as per your question), then you'll want to use `fooList.insert( INSERT_INDEX, ELEMENT_TO_INSERT )`

Explicitly

```
>>> list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> list_to_add=["A","B","C"]
>>> list_of_lists.insert(0,list_to_add) # index 0 to add to front
>>> print list_of_lists
[['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

There is more information regarding List API [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (append) to do it like this:

```py
list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
list_to_add=["A","B","C"]

list_of_lists.append(list_to_add)
```

And you should get the intended result.

```py
>>> list_of_lists
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

In case you want it in the beginning you could wrap the "list_to_add" into a list then add to it the elements of "list_of_lists" like this:

```py
outpu_list = [list_to_add] + list_of_lists
```

```py
>>> output_list
[['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Otherwise if you want the freedom to insert at any index check @Locke's answer.

Comment: that's not what OP wanted.